# Change status bar color on two different activities

Tags: android, kotlin

I know how to set the status bar color across my app using style.xml but how do I change it on different activities?

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorBlueLight</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a second theme in your styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Secondary">
    <!-- set your attributes here -->
</style>
```

And then, in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, set your other activity to use the other theme:

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourSecondActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Secondary"/>
```

Comment: Ok, I understand that now. How do I call that theme in the activity now?

Comment: @SebastienDesemberg It is described in the answer. You don't have to call it, just define it in the Manifest.

Comment: Got it, I'm new :) Tnx

Answer (score 2):

You can create multiple custom themes and assign them to each `Activity` on `AndroidManifest.xml` such as:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/CustomTheme1">
<activity android:theme="@style/CustomTheme2">
```

Comment: Ok but how do I assign the theme to the activity?

Comment: If you define it in the Manifest like this, it’s automatically assigned, as the other answer stated as well in the comments.